# Summarizing dataframe and sorting with inserting 0 if the target words doesn't exist

Tags: arrays, matlab, sorting, matrix, merge

I have a tab-delimited data frame like this:

```
Sample  1
A   2
B   1
D   2
Sample  2
C   1
D   1
E   2
Sample  3
D   1
E   3
Sample  4
A   1
E   3
Sample  5
A   2
B   3
Sample  6
C   1
D   2
Sample  7
D   1
E   3
Sample  8
A   3
D   2
Sample  9
A   1
Sample  10
A   1
C   2
E   3
```

and I would like to transpose it and link the alphabets and the associated values. If the sample does not contain alphabets, I want "0" inserted.

So the modified dataframe I desire is

```
Sample  A   B   C   D   E
    1   2   1   0   2   0
    2   0   0   1   1   1
    3   0   0   0   1   3
    4   1   0   0   0   3
    5   2   3   0   0   0
    6   0   0   1   2   0
    7   0   0   0   1   3
    8   3   0   0   2   0
    9   1   0   0   0   0
    10  1   0   2   0   3
```

I tried to summarize the datafreame, and then transpose it. When I used,

```
awk 'NR==1{print} NR>1{a[$1]=a[$1]" "$2}END{for (i in a){print i " " a[i]}}' TEST
```

the output data was

```
Sample  1
A  2 1 2 3 1 1
B  1 3
C  1 1 2
D  2 1 1 2 1 2
E  2 3 3 3 3
Sample  2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10
```

Sample 1 was isolated, and there was no space when the alphabets were not included by the samples.

I hope that makes sense.